# iOS: the background of the home indicator(area below toolbar) grayed for a while during push

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

The toolbar's translucent is false. The color of the toolbar and the area below toolbar is white. When pushing a new view controller of the same class(both have toolbar in the bottom), the color of the area below toolbar will be changed to gray and then back to white at the end.

If I set the background color for the navigation controller or the key window to red, the red color will also be darkened a little bit during transition.

This problem occurs in iOS 13, 14, 15, and maybe present from the beginning since the introduction of iPhone X.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

-Xiang

Answer (score 0):

It seems during push transition, the old tableview are also grayed, which make the area below toolbar become gray.

My final solution is to make the toolbar extend to outside safe area by setting clip bounds to false.